# How to resolve a category from a property table in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, pivot, join, resolve, unpivot

By way of an example, lets say I have the following (simplified) table (called NumericValue):

```
Age   Gender    Occupation      Location        Value
40    M         Accountant      Johannesburg    100
40    F         Accountant      Johannesburg    120
40    M         Engineer        NULL            110
40    F         Engineer        NULL            110
```

Now suppose I have this table called Employees:

```
Employee Number  Age   Gender    Occupation      Location        
1000123          40    F         Engineer        Cape Town      
1000124          40    M         Accountant      Johannesburg
```

Now, what I need is to select the "value" field for these two employees. And let's say that engineers will never ever have a "location" in the NumericValue table, so I can't just do a simple join. In stead, I reformat my "NumericTable" as follows:

```
Table: "CategoryValue"
Category   Value
1          100
2          120
3          110
4          110
```

With a "property" table like this:

```
Table: "CategoryProperty"
Category   FieldName   FieldValue
1          Age         40
1          Gender      M
1          Occupation  Accountant
1          Location    Johannesburg
.
.
4          Age         40
4          Gender      F
4          Occupation  Engineer
```

(note, no entry for "location" under category 4, which refers to the 40 year old female engineer)

Which makes sense to me, since I only have entries where a specific categorisation field is of importance. But how do I resolve this and extract the Value field for the specific employee?

Thanks
Karl

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do something like this?

```
Select  e.EmployeeNumber,
        e.Age,
        e.Gender,
        e.Occupation,
        e.Location,
        nv.Value
From Employees e
Join NumericValue nv on e.Age = nv.Age
                        And e.Gender = nv.Gender
                        And e.Occupation = nv.Occupation
                        And e.Location = IsNull(nv.Location, e.Location)
```

Just replace the NumericValue Location with the value of the Employee Location when it is NULL